# If $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to F$ is an onto morphism and $F$ is a field, then $\mathbb{Z}_p\cong F$ where $p$ is a prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Let $F$ a field ed $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to F$ an onto morphism. We know that $\ker f$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, then $\ker f=(n)=n\mathbb{Z}$ for same $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. For the first isomorphism theorem we have that $$\mathbb{Z}_n:=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/\ker f\cong F.$$

Now, if $n=0$, the canonical projection is $\pi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$, but the only non-zero morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is $id_{\mathbb{Z}}$ which is, in particular, injective. Since $\ker f=n\mathbb{Z}$, then $\tilde{f}\colon\mathbb{Z}\to F$ is injective, but for the first isomorphism theorem $f=\tilde{f}\circ\pi$, then $f$ is injective, moreover, for hypotesis, $f$ is onto, then $f$ is an isomorphism. But this is absurd, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field. Therefore $n$ can not be $0$.

On the other hand $\mathbb{Z}_n\cong F$, then $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field, then $n$ must be prime.

Correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your claim. $\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to a field because it is not a field: $2$ has no multiplicative inverse. And there is an onto homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to a field, take the quotient map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for prime $p$. But obviously not every field is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}$ (e.g. reals).

Comment: Sorry but I have not explained well, now I correct my question.

Comment: The kernel cannot be zero, since this would imply that $2$, for exemple, has multiplicative inverse (since its image in F does). Now, by the isomorphism theorem you have $Z/nZ \cong F$. Thus, $Z/nZ$ is a field. Now prove that $n$ must be prime.

Comment: @math.h I would like to know if the way I have shown that $n$ can not be zero is correct

Comment: Yes, it is. But I think you are "talking too much" (no offense, really) for just a simple thing. The morphism $Z\rightarrow F$ cannot be injective (otherwise the morphism would be bijective), since $F$ is a field. You seem to know that $Z$ can't be isomorphic to a field, so you gotta accept this argument. As you said, the kernel should be of the form: $nZ$. As it is not zero (the kernel), then $n$ cannot be zero.

Comment: Quite right! Thanks!

Comment: More simply: if $n=0$, then $f$ is injective; being surjective it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume $\ker(f)\neq (0)$, since this would imply that $\Bbb Z$ is a field.

Since $\Bbb Z$ is a PID, we can assume $\ker(f)=(n)$, where $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. You are ofcourse right that $\Bbb Z_n$ is a field $\iff n$ prime. One way to show this:

Suppose $n=ab$ so that $\ker(f)=(ab)$, then $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)=0$ in $F$. Since $F$ is a field, and so an integral domain we need to have $f(a)=0$ or $f(b)=0$, which forces either $a,b$ to be a unit. This means by definition that $n$ is prime.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeoutThanks for yourn answer. So my reasoning to show that $n$ can not be zero is correct?